# Replace in wall communications panel

Tags: stucco, coaxial-cable, weather-resistant

There's a cutout panel on one of my garage's exterior wall where I'd like to install a weatherproof plastic enclosure on top of.

There's a hole in it where the satellite installer got the coax cable to go through.

[image]

Door's held on by 1 screw and just leads to an empty wall cavity.

[image]

So I'm wondering what a good approach would be seal up the opening that would allow access to the communications wiring. My first thought was to mount the enclosure right over the opening and get as much of it covered as possible then stucco patch the rest. Another thought was to put a metal sheet over the opening, seal it up, and then mount the panel on that. Any other suggestions or reason those wouldn't work well would be appreciated.

Comment: Just buy a weatherproof communications box that's 14 inches, which are pretty commonly available on a brief look, and cut out the back as needed for access. *e.g.* https://duckduckgo.com/?q=14%22+weatherproof+communications+box&va=b&t=hc&ia=web